# Pick only the first value in an IF statement inside a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
... WHERE ... AND (IF(category.discount_value > 0, product_sizes.product_price * (1-category.discount_value/100),
        IF(sub_category.discount_value > 0,product_sizes.product_price * (1-sub_category.discount_value/100),
        IF(discount.product_id = product.id AND discount.from_date < now() AND discount.to_date >= now() AND discount.status = 1, product_sizes.product_price * (1-discount.percent/100),product_sizes.product_price)
        )
        )) >= 100 ...
```

Note that this is a part of the query, it is a long query so I'm trying to make it simpler to understand my problem.

And consider the table `product_sizes`:

```
product_id | price
         1 | 50
         1 | 110
```

Basically, I'm checking for a discount on the category, if there's no discount, I check if there's one for the subcategory, and finally if the item itself has a discount if both are false.

The problem is, I want the to take the first item (with price `50`) when using `product_sizes.price` in the code here and use it as the maximum/minimum value so in this case it won't show up in the result, but it is now taking the last one instead most of the times.

I tried to add an alias, but then I can't use that alias in the `WHERE` clause, and the `HAVING` clause solution ignores `GROUP BY` so it is also not working.

Also, a subquery can't use a value from the parent query so it won't work for me. I'm using a `product.id` given by the query itself too.

I hope you can understand what's the issue. I'm looking for something like a function or something to use like this `FIRST_V(product_sizes.product_price)`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you seem to have two prices for this product. In which sense is this the "first"? is it because it's the smallest? or is there another field (like change_date) in the table which controls the ordering?

Comment: @YossiVainshtein there are multiple sizes and each size has a different price, I want the first size added of that product to be picked, could work if we choose the size with the smallest price too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select price from (select product_id,min(price) as price from product_sizes group by product_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did that and it worked! I also now know a new thing, which will make other tasks easier for me. That was really helpful :)